# How to log a given instance of a scaled service with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file which contains, among others, an application service `app`.

When I start this service using the `up --scale app=N` option (with N>1) I can monitor what's happening in the service using `docker-compose logs app` but this list *all* the instances of the app service, namely, `app_1`, `app_2`, ..., `app_N`.

Let's say I'd like to only see the logs of the `app_4`. How could I achieve that?

The help doesn't help me much on that:

```
ubuntu-host-machine$ docker-compose logs --help
View output from containers.

Usage: logs [options] [--] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --no-color          Produce monochrome output.
    -f, --follow        Follow log output.
    -t, --timestamps    Show timestamps.
    --tail="all"        Number of lines to show from the end of the logs
                        for each container.
```

I naturally tried `docker-compose logs app_4` but without much success, as it says:

```
ERROR: No such service: app_4
```

The same error appears if I want, e.g. to `stop` the `app_4` using `docker-compose stop app_4` and will probably for other similar commands. So the question may also apply to these similar situations.

Versioning information:

```
ubuntu-host-machine$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

ubuntu-host-machine$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

ubuntu-host-machine$ uname -mor
5.4.0-81-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You could upvote https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8636 where the request is tracked

Answer (score 1):

Since there is still no official option for this, I'm writing an obvious solution that might not come in mind: using `grep`

If you do

```
docker compose logs app | grep app_2
```

You will get the logs for a specific instance of the scaled service